# frame.add(game); not working

Tags: java, swing, game-engine

I'm new to java and have decided to make a simple game. I found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH1xpfOBN6M&list=ELmvNdIhZY1t4 and this is my   code:

```
package com.MyGame.Display;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final String TITLE = "MyGame Version Pre-Alpha 0.1";

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

There seems to be an error with the frame.add(game); code but nothing that I do works. I've tried everything. The error is  "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments ". It should be a quick fix so I hope you can help!

Comment: `Display` is not a swing component.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to add a Display object into a JFrame, but what is this Display object? It doesn't extend any Swing components such as a JPanel, and so you really can't add it to a JFrame since doing so has no meaning, makes no sense.

Consider:

- having Display extend JPanel
- Reading/studying the Swing tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).
- Also go through the basic Java tutorials and learn to use and use frequently the Java API.

Comment: so if I remove frame.add(game); completely it will work?

Comment: @tacomanmagic: this question is best asked by trying. But I can tell you that likely your code will *compile*, but will it do anything meaningful? Likely not.

Answer (score 0):

You need Display to extend (IN TERMS OF THAT TUTORIAL)Canvas.  You cant add random things to JFrames in Java.

Better to do something like this

```
 public class Game extends JFrame {

   public Game() {

       initUI();
   }  

   private void initUI() {


       pack();
       repaint();

       setResizable(false);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Game g = new Game();
               g.setVisible(true);
               running = true;
               Update update = new Update();
           }
       });

   }
```

Comment: No, **please** don't advise him to mix AWT and Swing components.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what in [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH1xpfOBN6M&list=ELmvNdIhZY1t4) ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: then it's a terrible and out of date tutorial. Better to start with the Swing tutorials.

Comment: I was just correcting him for what was in that tutorial.  And yes it is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late now but:

```
public class Display extends Canvas { <--here

}
```

I followed the same tutorial and got the same problem but solved it with this